# Migrating Multisite with WP-Cli and/or Search-Replace-DB

Tags: multisite, migration, wp-cli, localhost

I have a Wordpress 5.5 / PHP7.3 MultiSite production site installation that I am trying to migrate to my local LAMP dev environment so that I can edit.

**The Problem:** is that when I run Search-Replace-DB script or the WP-Cli multisite migration scripts.  One subsite loads perfectly on the new development domain, meanwhile the primary site and a subsite that have the same theme, successfully loads, but the theme seems broken (visual composer based). Possible, additional non-visual errors as well.

I have download the all the files, configured LAMP virtualhost correctly, and imported the database to my local LAMP environment via PHPMYADMIN (**NOTE:** Prior to exporting the production db, I network deactivated the Yoast SEO plugin).

My MultiSite has the following urls that need to be changed:

1.) example.org   -->   localhost.example.org

2.) webinar.example.org --> webinar.localhost.example.org

3.) blog.example.org --> blog.localhost.example.org  (domain mapped to "otherdomainname.org")  --Works flawlessly

**ERROR MESSAGES:**

Despite, network deactivating the Yoast SEO plugin, prior to exporting to the production as recommended, I receive the following error when I execute Search-Replace-DB:

```
The dry-run option was selected. No replacements will be made.

The table "tclrx_2_cleantalk_sfw" has no primary key. Changes will have to be made manually.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

    
2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

This is usually caused by a plugin storing classes as a serialised string which other PHP classes can't then access. It is not possible to unserialise this data because the PHP can't access this class. P.S. It's most commonly a Yoast plugin that causes this error. Your changes will still have taken place within the rest of the database.

The table "tclrx_7_cleantalk_sfw" has no primary key. Changes will have to be made manually.

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_NullSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_NullSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_NullSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_NullSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

The table "tclrx_cleantalk_sfw" has no primary key. Changes will have to be made manually.

syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting '{'

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'FS_Plugin' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833

2: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'WP_User' in /var/www/html/example.org/DP-Search-Replace-DB/srdb.class.php on line 833
```

When Search-Replace-DB is executed (not dry-run), I get the problem described above: broken theme, possibly other non-visual errors.

So, at this poitn I install WP-Cli and ran the following multisite compatible migration script that that I [found here](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/):

```
# Bash script: Search/replace production to development url (multisite compatible)
#!/bin/bash
if $(wp --url=example.org core is-installed --network); then
    wp search-replace --url=example.org 'example.org' 'localhost.example.org' --recurse-objects --network --skip-columns=guid --skip-tables=wp_users
else
    wp search-replace 'example.org' 'example.org' --recurse-objects --skip-columns=guid --skip-tables=wp_users
fi
```

It excutes successfully, but generates the following errors:

```
Warning: Skipping an uninitialized class "Stripe\ApplePayDomain", replacements might not be complete.
Warning: Skipping an uninitialized class "FS_Plugin", replacements might not be complete.
Warning: Skipping an uninitialized class "FS_Plugin", replacements might not be complete.
+------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+------+
| Table                  | Column                | Replacements | Type |
+------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+------+
| wp_2_commentmeta    | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_commentmeta    | meta_value            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_comments       | comment_author        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_comments       | comment_author_email  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_comments       | comment_author_url    | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_comments       | comment_author_IP     | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_comments       | comment_content       | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_comments       | comment_approved      | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_comments       | comment_agent         | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_comments       | comment_type          | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_links          | link_url              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_links          | link_name             | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_links          | link_image            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_links          | link_target           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_links          | link_description      | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_links          | link_visible          | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_links          | link_rel              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_links          | link_notes            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_links          | link_rss              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_options        | option_name           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_options        | option_value          | 48           | PHP  |
| wp_2_options        | autoload              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_postmeta       | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_postmeta       | meta_value            | 2            | PHP  |
| wp_2_posts          | post_content          | 889          | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | post_title            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | post_excerpt          | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | post_status           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | comment_status        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | ping_status           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | post_password         | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | post_name             | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | to_ping               | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | pinged                | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | post_content_filtered | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_2_posts          | post_type             | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_posts          | post_mime_type        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_term_taxonomy  | taxonomy              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_term_taxonomy  | description           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_termmeta       | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_termmeta       | meta_value            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_terms          | name                  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_2_terms          | slug                  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_commentmeta    | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_commentmeta    | meta_value            | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_7_comments       | comment_author        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_comments       | comment_author_email  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_comments       | comment_author_url    | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_comments       | comment_author_IP     | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_comments       | comment_content       | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_comments       | comment_approved      | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_comments       | comment_agent         | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_comments       | comment_type          | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_links          | link_url              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_links          | link_name             | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_links          | link_image            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_links          | link_target           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_links          | link_description      | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_links          | link_visible          | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_links          | link_rel              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_links          | link_notes            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_links          | link_rss              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_options        | option_name           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_options        | option_value          | 13           | PHP  |
| wp_7_options        | autoload              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_postmeta       | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_postmeta       | meta_value            | 91           | PHP  |
| wp_7_posts          | post_content          | 22           | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | post_title            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | post_excerpt          | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | post_status           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | comment_status        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | ping_status           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | post_password         | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | post_name             | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | to_ping               | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | pinged                | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | post_content_filtered | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_7_posts          | post_type             | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_posts          | post_mime_type        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_term_taxonomy  | taxonomy              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_term_taxonomy  | description           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_termmeta       | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_termmeta       | meta_value            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_terms          | name                  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_7_terms          | slug                  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_blogmeta         | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_blogmeta         | meta_value            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_blogs            | domain                | 3            | SQL  |
| wp_blogs            | path                  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_commentmeta      | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_commentmeta      | meta_value            | 24           | PHP  |
| wp_comments         | comment_author        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_comments         | comment_author_email  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_comments         | comment_author_url    | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_comments         | comment_author_IP     | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_comments         | comment_content       | 11           | SQL  |
| wp_comments         | comment_approved      | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_comments         | comment_agent         | 21           | SQL  |
| wp_comments         | comment_type          | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_links            | link_url              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_links            | link_name             | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_links            | link_image            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_links            | link_target           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_links            | link_description      | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_links            | link_visible          | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_links            | link_rel              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_links            | link_notes            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_links            | link_rss              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_options          | option_name           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_options          | option_value          | 33           | PHP  |
| wp_options          | autoload              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_postmeta         | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_postmeta         | meta_value            | 31           | PHP  |
| wp_posts            | post_content          | 488          | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | post_title            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | post_excerpt          | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | post_status           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | comment_status        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | ping_status           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | post_password         | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | post_name             | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | to_ping               | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | pinged                | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | post_content_filtered | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts            | post_type             | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_posts            | post_mime_type        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_registration_log | email                 | 6            | SQL  |
| wp_registration_log | IP                    | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_signups          | domain                | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_signups          | path                  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_signups          | title                 | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_signups          | user_login            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_signups          | user_email            | 2            | SQL  |
| wp_signups          | activation_key        | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_signups          | meta                  | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_site             | domain                | 1            | SQL  |
| wp_site             | path                  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_sitemeta         | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_sitemeta         | meta_value            | 10           | PHP  |
| wp_term_taxonomy    | taxonomy              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_term_taxonomy    | description           | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_termmeta         | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_termmeta         | meta_value            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_terms            | name                  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_terms            | slug                  | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_usermeta         | meta_key              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_usermeta         | meta_value            | 9            | PHP  |
| wp_users            | user_login            | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_users            | user_nicename         | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_users            | user_email            | 5            | SQL  |
| wp_users            | user_url              | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_users            | user_activation_key   | 0            | SQL  |
| wp_users            | display_name          | 0            | SQL  |
+------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+------+
Success: Made 1709 replacements.
```

These two quasi-different methods of db migration, are causing the exact same errors, so I am clearly missing something.

Any Tips?

Answer (score 3):

Accepting a little egg on my face.  Dumb-dumb error.

The above migration was 100% successful despite the error messages from WP-Cli and Search Replace DB.  The reason that my theme appeared broken and other weird issues.. I forgot to re-enable my plugins folder that had been re-named "plugins_temp_disabled", while troubleshooting a different problem. Good night of sleep and I caught the problem.  I highly recommend WP-Cli for migrating multsite or single site wordpress because some plugins can be buggy at key moments of your migration process.  Old skool...